# How to get the latest tag in git (consistently)?

Tags: git

In some projects, the `git describe --tags` command returns the exact lastest tag name, but in other cases it returns extra information:

```
project1> git describe --tags
2.0-BETA6

project2> git describe --tags
1.5-13-g4abc82e
```

Is there a way to call git describe so that it returns either just the first format (TAG only) or just the second format (TAG with commit info).

I am trying to update a java properies file to contain a property with the most recent tag, and another property with the most recent commit.

*In case it matters, im using "git version 1.7.9.6 (Apple Git-31.1)"*

Answer (score 1):

To get the latest tag in all branches:

```
git describe --tags `git rev-list --tags --max-count=1`
```